# Twitter API, what do these XML tags mean

Tags: xml, twitter

Quick question and probably an easy one for hardcore twitter users (which I'm not).
Ex.  https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=barackobama

What do

```
<friends_count>

<listed_count>

<retweet_count> 

<favorited_count>
```

stand for?

- Friends_Count, all his/her friends? I'm not sure because I don't know if it's possible to add friends on twitter. I thought I'd only could add people to follow.
- Listed_count : is this the amount of times he/she IS listed, or he / she HAS listed someone
- retweet_count: is this the amount of how many times he/she IS retweeted of HAS retweeted?
- favorited_count: is this the amountof how many times he/she IS favorited or HAS favorited

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<friends_count>
```

The number of people someone is following.  Dubbed "your friends"

```
<listed_count>
```

The number of public lists on which the user appears.

```
<retweet_count>
```

Applies  to the current user's status, and this is the number of times it's been RT'd

```
<favorited_count>
```

As above, this is the number of times that status has been favourited.

[Source](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/08/30/twitter-api-adds-retweet-count-and-more/) and personal experience

Comment: thanks. So retweet and favorited only applies to the last status?

Comment: On the user object's xml dump, yes.. If you look at their statuses.xml, then it applies to every status object on it.

Comment: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=barackobama Does this include all statuses? So if I would do a count of all retweet counts here, I would have the total retweet number?